# Shiny Programming Error: Warning: Error in sourceUTF8: Stack trace (innermost first):

Tags: r, shiny, probability

I'm coding a logistic regression app with several conditional panels that should show the resulting probability depending upon the prompt that the user selects... but instead the page doesn't load when I run the app and I get an error like:

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6497 Error in parse(file, keep.source =
>   FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) unexpected end of input 172:   )
>   173: 
>       ^ Warning: Error in sourceUTF8: Error sourcing C:\Users Stack trace (innermost first):
>       1: runApp

Should I be using a switch case in server.R instead? Thanks.

```
    UI.R
    pageWithSidebar(

    # Application title
    headerPanel("Steadylosing NBA Probability Set (5200+ Observations)"),


        # Sidebar with conditional slider inputs 
        sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "Occur",
        "Pick One Outcome to Predict:",
        choices = c(
          "TeamAWin",
          "BothTeamsAllow110+"
        )
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.Occur == 'TeamAWin",
        sliderInput("aoff", "A's Offensive Rating", 90, 125, 100, .1),
        sliderInput("adef", "A's Defensive Rating", 90, 125, 100, .1),
        sliderInput("boff", "B's Offensive Rating", 90, 125, 100, .1),
        sliderInput("bdef", "B's Defensive Rating", 90, 125, 100, .1),
        selectInput("homecourt", "Homecourt, Yes or No?", choices = c(0, 1))
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.Occur == 'BothTeamsAllow110+",
        sliderInput("aoff2", "A's Offensive Rating", 90, 125, 100, .1),
        sliderInput("adef2", "A's Defensive Rating", 90, 125, 100, .1),
        sliderInput("boff2", "B's Offensive Rating", 90, 125, 100, .1),
        sliderInput("bdef2", "B's Defensive Rating", 90, 125, 100, .1),
        selectInput("ot2", "Overtime, Yes or No?", choices = c(0, 1)),
        sliderInput("combpace2", "Combined Pace of the Two Teams", 170, 220,     200, .1)
      )

    ),

    # Show prediction values
      mainPanel(

      h2(textOutput("Prediction1")),

      h2(textOutput("Prediction2"))
  )




Server.R 
        shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  sliderValues <- reactive({

    # Compose data frame
    data.frame(
      Name = c("aoff", #TeamAoffrtg
               "adef", #TeamAdefrtg
               "boff", #TeamBoffrtg
               "bdef", #TeamBdefrtg
               "homecourt",
               "aoff2", #TeamAoffrtg
               "adef2", #TeamAdefrtg
               "boff2", #TeamBoffrtg
               "bdef2", #TeamBdefrtg
               "ot2", #Overtime
               "combpace2"),

      Value = as.double(c(input$aoff,
                          input$adef,
                          input$boff,
                          input$bdef,
                          input$homecourt,input$aoff2,
                          input$adef2,
                          input$boff2,
                          input$bdef2,
                          input$ot2,
                          input$combpace2)),
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  } )

  function1 <- function(aoff,adef,boff,bdef,homecourt) {
    100*((exp(-1.9418+.1572*aoff-.144*adef-.139*boff+.1414*bdef+.4341*homecourt))/(1+exp(-1.9418+.1572*aoff-.144*adef-.139*boff+.1414*bdef+.4341*homecourt)))
  }
  function2 <- function(aoff2,adef,boff,bdef,ot2,combpace2) {
    100*((exp(-74.6058-.0788*aoff2+.0874*adef+.0795*boff-.09166*bdef+2.8053*ot2+.1897*combpace2))/(1+exp(-74.6058-.0788*aoff2+.0874*adef+.0795*boff-.09166*bdef+2.8053*ot2+.1897*combpace2)))
  }
  output$Prediction1 <- renderText({
    predtype <- input$Occur
    if (predtype == "TeamAWin"){
    c(round(function1((input$aoff),(input$adef),(input$boff),(input$bdef),(input$homecourt)),4),"%")

    }
    })
  output$Prediction2 <- renderText({  predtype <- input$Occur
    if (predtype == "BothTeamsAllow110+"){
    c(round(function2(input$aoff2, input$adef2,input$boff2,input$bdef2,input$ot2,input$combpace2),4),"%")

    }
  })

  else {
 return()
   }

}
)
```

Comment: That error means you are missing a closing bracket in your code

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Instead, it turns into an (argument  "Main Panel" is missing with no default error), although I have a main panel in the UI.

Comment: I got a similar error, when I finally found that I had an odd character (in spanish) indeed. I didn't get this error any more, removing that character!